# Can I make my program show itself from another program

Tags: c#, shared-libraries, mutex

That may be a poor title, but I don't know how else to phrase it. So here is what I have.

I have one program that acts as a keyboard hook. It traps F13-F24 so that a person can assign those keys to do a few different tasks.

One of the programs that it can open is our own brew of a On-Screen Keyboard.

Both of those programs I have source code for, but I did not make either of them rather I inherited them from someone else. As I was reviewing the code to fix a few of the bugs in it I noticed that The first program calls upon the second program in a strange way. A way that I don't like.

```
        IntPtr hWnd = new IntPtr();
        currentoggle = true;
        currentmultiple = false;

        System.Diagnostics.Process[] p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("CustomOsk");
        if (p.Length > 0)
        {
            Globals.trace.TraceInformation("OSK loaded");

            string window = "";
            switch (currentparms.ToLower()[0])
            {
                case 's':
                    window = "Custom OSK AN";
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    window = "Custom OSK EK";
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    window = "Custom OSK NP";
                    break;
                default:
                    window = "";
                    break;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(window))
            {
                hWnd = User32.FindWindow(null, window);
                if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    User32.PostMessage(hWnd, WM_TOGGLEONOFF, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                    Globals.trace.TraceInformation("ProcessKeyboard()-");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        Globals.trace.TraceInformation("OSK Start");
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\CustomOsk.exe", currentparms);
        Globals.trace.TraceInformation("ProcessKeyboard()-");
```

I just don't think I should have to look through all my processes to see if our custom OSK is turned on when I have the source code. I think that I should be able to make calls directly too it in some form or another. So then I thought, well **IF** I can make use of Mutex statements, maybe I can try to find that Mutex Pointer, then send a message to that pointer to change the state of my Custom OSK... but then I thought well that might not work so good if i want to make either of the programs more complex in the future.

I figured at this point it would be a good idea to ask around and ask what would be a good solution for this?

Another thoought I had is, would it be a stupid make the OSK into a library, then i can just reference that library in my keyboard hook program. To keep it so that a person can open up the On Screen Program as a seperate program I could make another very simple program that calls on this library again. That seems best to me, but I would like to know if there is a different solution for what I have in place already. Your thouoghts

**Edited for clarity of issue**

Comment: You lost me after "I don't like..". What are you trying to achieve? Which program is under your control and which isn't?

Comment: @dtb both are under my control now.

Comment: @dtb I rephrased my post.. Hopefully it makes more sense now. Sorry about the confusion.